# Populate listview using SimpleCursorAdapter in Android

Tags: java, android, database, listview, simplecursoradapter

I know this question has been asked and answered before, but I have followed multiple tutorials to no avail.

I just thought if I put my code up maybe someone could help and point me in the right direction. I am not going to lie, I am a massive noob at this but am loving it so far (well, up to this point anyway). All that is happening is when I load the activity, it just force closes with the following error message:

```
06-14 20:04:08.162: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17605): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.magic8/com.example.magic8.AnswerList}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView
```

So, here it is. My database query is:

```
public Cursor fetchAnswersList() {
    return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, "answer"}, 
    null, null, null, null, null, null);    
}
```

Then my list view code:

```
public class AnswerList extends Activity {

private Context context;
private DatabaseManager mDbHelper;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.answerlist);        

    Cursor answers = mDbHelper.fetchAnswersList();
    startManagingCursor(answers);

    ListView answerList=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.answerList);    

    String[] from = new String[] {"_id", "answer"};
    int[] to = new int[] {R.id.answerItem};
    SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(context, R.layout.list_item, answers, from, to);
    answerList.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);

    answerList.setOnItemClickListener(
        new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
          // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
          setToast("Answer: " + ((TextView) view).getText());
        }
    });
}
```

And last but not least, here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/addAnswerForm" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/addAnswer"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content">
            <requestFocus></requestFocus>
        </EditText>
        <Button 
        android:text="Add" 
        android:id="@+id/addAnswer_btn" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </Button>
     </LinearLayout>
     <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/answers" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <ListView 
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/answerList" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/answerItem" 
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent">
        </TextView>
    </ListView>
     </LinearLayout>   

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Did you try to use ListActivity instead of Activity?

Comment: Hi, Yea I have. Am I right in thinking that if there is more than a list in the activity I need to use Activity rather than ListActivity?

At the moment there is only a list, but there is a textbox and button in the XML as I want to be able to allow the user to add their own answers to the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you are getting is most likely because you're trying to embed a TextView into a ListView...

```
<ListView 
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/answerList" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/answerItem" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
    </TextView>
</ListView>
```

Remove the TextView from the ListView and then try the following...

```
String[] from = new String[] {"answer"};
int[] to = new int[] {android.R.id.text1};
SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, answers, from, to);
```

This uses the pre-defined Android `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` and `android.R.id.text1`

Comment: Thank you both for answering me so quickly after posting, I really appreciate it.

I now have the following code, and I am still getting a force close:

    `ListView answerList=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.answerList);
        
        String[] from = new String[] {"answer"};
        int[] to = new int[] {android.R.id.text1};
        SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, answers, from, to);
        answerList.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);`

My err msg:
Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Comment: @javaMonkey: Did you change Activity to ListActivity? If so, you've just slightly complicated things.

Comment: Weird, now I am trying and getting this error:

`06-14 21:23:17.852: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19652): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.magic8/com.example.magic8.AnswerList}: java.lang.NullPointerException`. I have looked into what this means, but I can't see anything causing it.

Comment: @MisterSquonk No, I didn't change it to ListActivity.

Comment: @javaMonkey: Try changing the 'id' for your ListView in the xml file to `android:id="@android:id/list"` - you'll also have to change it for `findViewById(android.R.id.list)`

Comment: @MisterSquonk It's not liking that. Eclipse is giving me the error: `Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'id' with value '@android:id/answerList').`

Comment: @MisterSquonk Sorry, I didn't realise that it had to be @android:id/list exactly, I have changed it to this now and I am getting a force close on app start with the error `06-14 22:15:01.892: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19997): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.magic8/com.example.magic8.Magic8Ball}: java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: @MisterSquonk: Apparently it's on the `Cursor answers = mDbHelper.fetchAnswersList();` line. I am getting the error mDbHelper = null.

Comment: @javaMonkey: OK so it looks like the query is failing. Have you verified that `DATABASE_TABLE` is the correct name for your table and `KEY_ROWID`  and `"answer"` are valid for the table's column names?

Comment: @MisterSquonk: I have been looking into it and yes, the table and fields are correct. I hadn't opened the mDbHelper [mDbHelper.open()] as I was under the impression that if I opened it in the main activity (Magic8Ball.java), I wouldn't have to open it again. Anyway, I opened it and I got the error 'column _id does not exist'. So I added it to the query `String query = "SELECT " + KEY_ROWID + ", answer FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE;`. I ran it again and I am getting the NullPointerException error again and I can't seem to debug it as I get the error "the source attachment does not contain the file.."

Comment: @javaMonkey: What are the actual column names of your table?

Comment: @MisterSquonk: I only have three columns: 1) "_id"   2) "answer"  3) "editable"  -  the table name is "answers"

Comment: @MisterSquonk: I would just like to take this oppertunity to thank you for coming on here and helping me. I really do appreciate it and once it's working, I am going to study the code HARD until I fully understand what broke it. I am getting there, slowly, but enjoying it.

Thanks Again!

Comment: @MisterSquonk: IT WORKS!!!! I cant believe I have been so flipping stupid! `SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, answers, from, to);` should have been `SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, answers, from, to);` - Replacing "context" with "this"

Comment: @javaMonkey: You and me both (when it comes to being stupid ;) ). I thought there was something about it which didn't look right but didn't spot what it was. I'm glad it's working for you - seems to me you had a few different issues in there though. As you said in a comment above - study it HARD and learn from the different steps you went through. All part of the learning process. Have fun! :)

Comment: Yea, there was more to it than that and I thank you for helping me so much. I am going to look into styling my list now then comes trying to get my form working. Thanks again!! :D

Answer (score 2):

Your to and from need to be the same length. You don't need to include _id in the 'from' array. Note that you still need to have _id in your cursor.

Comment: Just like to thank you to for helping me, I really appreciate it!!